# SVG Export - Line Patterns not showing

Tags: microsoft-visio, svg

I am using visio to create technical drawings. My further workflow depends on using the svg export of this drawing. However, I stumbled into the following problem. The custom line patterns are not showing in the svg export. Please not: Standard dash patterns are exported correctly, but not user defined line patterns.

I have a route for a workaround, but this is quite cumbersome and not working correctly yet. My workaround would be to change the lines, with a custom line pattern to an emf beforehand (in this case they are shown correctly in the SVG export). However, this relies on a paste special command. When using the paste-special command visio quite arbitrarily chooses the position of the newly added shape. Aligning the old and new shape is quite tricky and does not overlap 100%. (I am trying to automate this via VBA).

Does anyone have suggestions for better workaroungs or a real fix for the export issue?